# click something on child window, selenium webdriver js

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

everyone!
I have to automate scenario- getting site by url
Click here button
Then site open child window, and there I have to click help button.
using selenium web driver and js

Hello, everyone!
I have to automate scenario- getting site by url
Click here button
Then site open child window, and there I have to click help button.
How I should code it?